# How to find the position of a character and extract a part of string using batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, registry, character, extract

My batch file reads the value of a registry key and stores its value in the variable `key`. So the value happens to be `"H:\KMSpico\KMSpico\Uninst.exe" /u0=KMSpico`
. I want to extract the part of this string that is enclosed in `""`. and store it in another variable, say `uninstall`. I could have easily done it by the following code: `SET uninstall=%key:~1,30%`. But the problem is that, the part before `Uninst.exe`, i.e. `H:\KMSpico\KMSpico\` which specifies the location of `Uninst.exe` might change depending upon the location where the user has installed the software, therefore the length of the part that is to be extracted might change. But the above code is set to extract the string only up to `30` characters.

Therefore, I wanted to know if there is way, so that we can somehow know the position of second `"` , so as to know the number of characters to be extracted. Or if there is some another way, to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple FOR loop preserves quoted values as a single string. You know it is the first value, so simply GOTO a label to break out of the loop after a single iteration.

```
for %%A in (%key%) do set "uninstall=%%A"&goto :break
:break
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a pirated windows?  :-)

try this

```
@echo off
rem :: I suppose you are capable to get the value from the registry and save is as variable.
set "reg_key="H:\KMSpico\KMSpico\Uninst.exe" /u0=KMSpico"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%a in ('%reg_key%') do set "uninstaler=%%~a"
echo %uninstaler%
```

Comment: This will not work if the path includes a space, comma, or semicolon. It might work if you set DELIMS to a double quote, but I'm not sure if you can guarantee that the path will always be quoted.